# Why is my action bar background overriden by the background attribute of my theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My ActionBar background color is partially overriden by my theme background. I want the entire ActionBar to be green. See the link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYx1t.jpg

The theme below is applied through the Manifest to the Activity holding the PreferenceFragment.

```
<!-- Settings theme -->
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@color/brown<item> 
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Yea sorry didn't have much time to work on it recently. Just tried it out and it worked. I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the main background, you want to set `android:windowBackground`, not `android:background`.

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/brown<item> 
</style>
```